# is it possible to set a promise in a signal handler?

Tags: c++, c++11, promise, signal-handling

I was looking for a way to stop a thread that perform a task every 2 seconds. I decided to try to use a std::promise/future so that the thread can exit immediately when the promise is set.

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <csignal>

std::promise<void> stop;

int main() {

    std::signal(SIGINT, [] (int)  { stop.set_value(); } );

    auto future = stop.get_future();

    while (future.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)) != std::future_status::ready) {
            std::cout << "I'm still there" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Actually this does not work and crashes that way:

> $ ./a.out  I'm still there
>   ^Cterminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
>   what():  Unknown error -1 Abandon
>   (core dumped)

Ok, One should take care of what he does in handler context, but I must say I was not expecting this crash; and I don't really understand it...
Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'd be expecting a crash?  Did you examine the insane restrictions signal handling has: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you have here is undefined behaviour as a result of calling a standard library function (not in list of signal safe functions) in the signal handler.

The limitations on the signal handler function (that is user-defined) are extensive and are [documented here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal).

Another thing to watch out for is if the signal handler refers to any object with static or thread-local(since C++11) storage duration that is not `std::atomic`(since C++11) or `volatile std::sig_atomic_t`.

And as @BasileStarynkevitch pointed out, if you are on Linux, ensure that only [async-signal-safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) functions are called from the signal handler.

Comment: On Linux, [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) is also *very* relevant

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Updated the answer with your comment.

Comment: I was expecting it, but the answer seems to be definitely no :)