# How to shutdown gRPC server from gRPC client in python?

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

I have a gRPC HelloWorld server running like shown in official getting started guide(https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/python/). 
I now want to shutdown/terminate the server from the client, possibly by calling a server method.
I know this can be done because I read this post on how to do this in c++. [How to shutdown gRPC server from Client (using RPC function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504208/how-to-shutdown-grpc-server-from-client-using-rpc-function)

My programming language is python for both client and server. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like in C++, calling [`Server.stop()`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html?highlight=shutdown#grpc.Server.stop) from a handler would be problematic. Instead, you should coordinate between your servicer thread and handler thread using, e.g., a [`threading.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html#threading.Event).

In your main thread, do something like

```py
stop_event = threading.Event()
server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor())
foo_pb2_grpc.add_FooServicer_to_server(Foo(stop_event), server)
server.add_insecure_port(...)
server.start()
stop_event.wait()
server.stop()
```

And then in your servicer, set the event when a shutdown is requested:

```py
class Foo(foo_pb2_grpc.FooServicer):
    def __init__(self, stop_event):
        self._stop_event = stop_event

    def Stop(self, request, context):
        self._stop_event.set()
        return foo_pb2.ShutdownResponse()
```

Comment: There seems to be a caveat in the `server.wait_for_termination()` source code: `threading.Event().wait()` does not work with CTRL+C across platforms. Will this affect the solution?

Comment: 1. This example doesn't use `wait_for_termination()`
2. Can you clarify what you mean by "doesn't work with CTRL+C". This question is about how to shut down a server based on an RPC, not based on CTRL+C. Are you wondering how to shut down a server based on either of these two events?